# Testing Android app behavior when an exception occur

Tags: android, testing, junit

How can I test my android app behavior when an exception occurs? 
I am using JUnit for unit & instrumented tests. Now I want to add some scenario with the exception, is there any solution to test my app behavior in this case (app crashes or not, warning/message/toast is displayed, ...)?